# How to list all registered VBoxHeadless VMs with their parameters?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

How to list all registered VBoxHeadless VMs with their parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VBoxManage list vms --long` will show you the parameters of all VMs; if you only want to see those with zero displays, you will have to postprocess the data.